# Using an internal class to make a custom object, creating an array of that object, and access information in that object using Java

Tags: java, class

Code first questions later...

```
public class Program2 
{
//The custom word object used when parsing the input file
class Word
{
    public String wordname;
    public int count;
    public int uniqueWord = 0;

    public Word(String word)
    {
        wordname = word;
        count = 1;
    }

    public boolean wordExists(String word)
    {
        if (word == this.wordname)
        {
            this.count++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public int getCount(Word word)
    {
        return this.count;
    }

    public String getName(Word word)
    {
        return this.wordname;
    }

}


// The main method
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //new array of words size 100
    Word[] words = new Word[100];
    //set the first word to bananna
    Word words[0] = new Word("bananna");
    //print bananna
    System.out.print(getName(words[0]));
}
}
```

Ok, so with what I know about Java, the code above should let me make an array of words, set the first to "bananna", and print it out. I have little experience making a custom class like this, and I can't find a good resource to model. Also, I am not 100% sure I understand calling static/nonstatic methods, so I'm sure some of the errors are from that as well.

What the program should do eventually, as a reference for why I am doing this, I have to take information in from a file (delimited strings aka Words) and see if it already exists in the array of words (and increment that word's count if it does), if it doesn't then make a new word.

Errors I'm getting are here:

---

```
Program2.java:116: ']' expected
            Word words[0] = new Word("bananna");
                       ^
Program2.java:116: illegal start of expression
            Word words[0] = new Word("bananna");
                        ^
2 errors
```

---

Any other information that you need let me know. I'll be back to check this post in an hour. Thank you for any help you have!

Comment: I am more than happy to help you. You can help by first posting your error messages here, rather than a link to the screen shot. Since you are using a command-line terminal, the usual Ctrl-C for copy won't work. Instead, click the icon at the top left corner and select Edit -> Copy from the menu. Then you can edit your question and paste here.

Comment: when you see `found: ____` followed by `required: ____` that means there is a mismatch between the type of object on the left hand side and the type on the right hand side. Start by fixing that and the rest will start to fall out for you

Comment: @Code-Guru thats a good trick to know, thank you. I'll use that in the future.

Comment: There is no reason for your `newWord` function to exist...

Comment: @Eric well that sure wasn't my brightest moment. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Word words = new Word[100];
```

Your main problem I can see is that `Word[100]` is an Array type that holds Word objects. You'll need the words variable to be of type `Word[]`, not just of type `Word`.

Regarding static and non-static, think of it this way: You've written a Word *class*, and then you can create as many Word *objects* as you like that belong to that class. When something is *static*, it means it belongs to the Word *class*, so it belongs to the definition of a word without belonging to any particular word. In contrast, something that is not *static* will belong to a particular Word object.

Comment: Ah i get it. The array syntax was a stupid mistake.

But I'm still lost on the static/nonstatic. I posted the new errors, and no matter how I change the methods I can't get it to work. I understand what you said in your 2nd paragraph, but I dont know how it applies to my class. Would the `wordExists, newWord, getCount, and getName` methods all be static as they are not an attribute of `Word`? Doing that gives more errors telling me inner classes can't be static or something

Comment: The way that Java is designed is that there's an implicit `this` in all non-static methods. So the instance methods that you've created that take a `Word word` parameter don't need them. However, because they pertain to a given word instance, they should still be static. Example: `Word watermelon = new Word("watermelon"); int count = watermelon.getCount();`

However some methods that don't pertain to a given word instance should still be static. For instance, `newWord(String)` does the same thing as the constructor, and doesn't refer to any form of `this`. Therefore `newWord` should be static.

Comment: @JeffBowman Correction: However, because they pertain to a given word instance, they should **not** be static.

Comment: @ZakParks I suggest removing the `newWord()` method altogether since you can do the same thing directly with the constructor. (Of course, you might be required to keep it if that is a constraint of the homework assignment. If so, ignore this suggestion.)

Comment: @Code-Guru no i removed it, i have no idea why i put that in there.I updated the OP after removing it

Comment: @Code-Guru: You're right, thanks. @ZakParks: You're almost there! Notice that you can't say `Word words[0] = new Word(...);`. There are two steps there, one to create the array (`Word[] words = new Word[length];`) and one to put a value into it (`words[0] = new Word(...);`). You don't need to declare that `words[0]` contains a word; based on your definition of `Word[] words` that's the only thing it can possibly contain.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors when you try to create the array, you should have:

```
Word[] words = new Word[100];
```

If you want to invoke `Word.newWord()` without calling the method on an *instance* of the Word class, this method needs to be `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the first error message. This is telling you that `Word[]` and `Word` are incompatible types. The `[]` at the end tells you that this is an array of `Word` objects. In other words, `Word words` declares a reference to a single `Word` object. Whereas your use of `new` allocates an array of them. To fix this simply change to `Word[] words`.

I won't go into detail about the other error messages because they will likely change after you fix this one. Good luck with your Java!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the way you are creating Array of Objects. You should declare the array of Class and then create objects:

```
//new array of words size 100
Word[] words = new Word[100];
```

//then Create objects

```
words[0] = new Word("apple");
```